# Soap message encoded in base64 binary data multiple files

Tags: soap, binary, base64, rfc

Recently I got a new project to work on a SOAP service and to Get and Post messages to a ASP.NET service based on xml.
The issue is that I managed to make the soap request and get the message.
The message looks like this:

```
UEsDBBQAAAAIAAdUe06+NXE0kR4AADLSAQALAAAAUHJvZHVzZS54bWzUXW1z48YN5k/h5EMnmbMsvomSpmkzFCXbjERJoSTb52/p9dq5mbxN2svczy/........
```

The message is Base64 Binary on RFC 4648 with multiple xml documents on it.
How I can construct this documents from the code in php?
The documents encrypted in this request are 3 xml files.
I managed to get them from an online decryptor called freeformatter with download function.
If I try to decode the result I get something like:

```
PKT{N�5q4�2�Produse.xml�]ms��
�O��C'��,����i3%یDI�$��o��ڹ��M����/�,��|vL�O�$�/�xv,,�u�s>9?;?....
```

Is there a solution for this?
I'm new to SOAP so I don't understand too much of it.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with `SOAP` itself. Base64 is a binary-encoding. If you decode it to binary (11010110 11010001 ..) you still got binaries. These binaries can be a file or something. You should ask yourself what you would do with a file read from Harddisk by a stream or something else which got you some binary-array. If you want to set up a SOAP-Client we need some more info how you want to..

Answer (score 1):

Thank you but i mannged to solve it.
I gonna post here the sollution so everyone who facing the same issue, get the response.
The first thing you need to do when you have an .zip file in a base64 binary string is to catch the response to a txt file.
Let's say the response from soap it's called ' $response ' and we need to catch this to an file. We do like this : 
    `$response = $client -> _getLastResponse();
     $fille = "response.xml";
     fille_put_contents($fille,$response);`

Now we got the response to an xml file.
The next thing to do is to get the response from xml values.
Lets say our value is `<ResponseFromServer>` .

```
`$b64 = "b64.txt";
 $dom = new DomDocument();
 $dom = load("response.xml");
 $data = $dom->getElementByTagName("ResponseFromServer");
 $catchb64 = $data;
 fille_put_content($b64,$catchb64);`
```

Now we got the clean Base64 Binary string in one fille.
The next thing we need is to create the document ( in this case is a .zip fille)

```
`$input_fille = "response.txt"; // the fille with clean base64 binary data on it
 $output_fille = "result.zip"; //the fille we need to create on system with the 
 documents decrypted
 $content = fille_get_contents($input_fille); // Reading the content of input fille
 $binary = base64_decode($content); // Decoding to binary
 fille_put_contents($output_fille,$binary); // Writing to fille the vallues`
```

We dont need the `ZipArchive()` function, because is allready a zip archive, all we need to do is to create a empty document and after to send the binary data to it.
Cheer's and goodluck!